# Query database starting from a certain id

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

My app's functionality is like Tinder. I will go through the work flow.

- App loads 10 `Hunts` (like tinder profiles)
- User accepts or rejects it
- Once user accepts or reject, hunt is removed (marked as seen so that it doesnt come back again )
- When `Hunts` count become 2 , app loads next 10 hunts. ( **This is not second page as `seen` hunts are already removed** )

Here is the tricky part. When it queries database again, the hunt would have the 2 hunts which user hasnt yet accepted or rejected. To avoid duplication I avoid first 2 hunts from the response. But problem occurs if the query is run after one more accept or reject. I would remove 2 hunts expecting normal behavior but this would remove eliminate one hunt which is not a duplicate.

What would a best solution would be to get all the hunts which comes after a certain `id`.I can use `WHERE NOT ID IN` by passing the ids. But I would like to know if there is a better solution as I see this would be a pretty common scenario .

I hope I made myself very clear.

The solutions which I have thought of but not really liked

1. Pass `ids` of the 2 hunts back and exclude them in the results
2. Remove duplicates from `hunts` once I receive response back in my app

All suggestions are welcome. I m using `Rails` so `active record` solutions are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It may be wise to add a `status` column with values 0,1,2 for `unseen`, `rejected`, `accepted`.

Then, when your user accepts / rejects each item, update that column.

To get the oldest (lowest-`id`-value) chunk of items for a user, use something like this.

```
      WHERE user=whatever AND status=0
      ORDER BY id
      LIMIT 10
```

Build an index on `(user, status, id)`, and MySQL can optimize this query.